# Least restrictive memory ordering for spin-lock with two atomics

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, atomic, memory-barriers

I have some worker threads performing time-critical processing at regular intervals (approx 1 kHz).  Each cycle, the workers are woken up to do a chore, each of which *should* (on average) be complete before the next cycle begins.  They operate on the same object, which can be occasionally modified by the main thread.

To prevent races, but allow a modification of the object to occur before the next cycle, I have used a spin-lock along with an atomic counter to record how many threads are still doing work:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void Modify();
    void DoWork( SomeContext& );
private:
    std::atomic_flag locked = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;
    std::atomic<int> workers_busy = 0;
};

void Foo::Modify()
{
    while( locked.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire ) ) ;   // spin
    while( workers_busy.load() != 0 ) ;                           // spin

    // Modifications happen here ....

    locked.clear( std::memory_order_release );
}

void Foo::DoWork( SomeContext& )
{
    while( locked.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire ) ) ;   // spin
    ++workers_busy;
    locked.clear( std::memory_order_release );
    
    // Processing happens here ....

    --workers_busy;
}
```

This allows all remaining work to be completed immediately, provided at least one thread has begun, and will always block before another worker can begin work for the next cycle.

The `atomic_flag` is accessed with "acquire" and "release" memory orders, as appears to be an accepted way of implementing spin-locks with C++11.  According to [documentation at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order):

> **`memory_order_acquire`** : A load operation with this memory order performs the *acquire operation* on the affected memory location: no memory accesses in the current thread can be reordered before this load. This ensures that all writes in other threads that release the same atomic variable are visible in the current thread.
>
> **`memory_order_release`** : A store operation with this memory order performs the *release operation*: no memory accesses in the current thread can be reordered after this store. This ensures that all writes in the current thread are visible in other threads that acquire the same atomic variable and writes that carry a dependency into the atomic variable become visible in other threads that consume the same atomic.

As I understand the above, this is enough to synchronise protected accesses across threads to provide mutex behaviour, without being overly conservative about memory ordering.

What I wish to know is whether the memory ordering can be further relaxed because a side-effect of this pattern is that I'm using a spin-lock mutex to synchronise another atomic variable.

The calls to `++workers_busy`, `--workers_busy` and `workers_busy.load()` all currently have the default memory order, `memory_order_seq_cst`.  Given that the only interesting use for this atomic is to unblock `Modify()` with `--workers_busy` (which is *not* synchronised by the spin-lock mutex), could the same acquire-release memory order be used with this variable, using a "relaxed" increment?  *i.e.*

```
void Foo::Modify()
{
    while( locked.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire ) ) ;
    while( workers_busy.load( std::memory_order_acquire ) != 0 ) ;  // <--
    // ....
    locked.clear( std::memory_order_release );
}

void Foo::DoWork( SomeContext& )
{
    while( locked.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire ) ) ;
    workers_busy.fetch_add( 1, std::memory_order_relaxed );         // <--
    locked.clear( std::memory_order_release );
    // ....
    workers_busy.fetch_sub( 1, std::memory_order_release );         // <--
}
```

Is this correct?  Is it possible for any of these memory orderings to be relaxed further?  And does it even matter?

Comment: Disclaimer: Not an expert on atomics. Wouldn't the `fetch_sub` outside the spin lock need to be at least `memory_order_acq_rel` to ensure it sees writes by other threads to the count, _and_ that other threads see the write it performs? Could be overlooking something.

Comment: What is your hardware platform?  Be aware that some of the memory ordering features of C++ are there for relatively esoteric platforms.  You might be doing a lot of work and learning for no direct benefit!

Comment: @Yakk: Just because no special hardware features are by some `memory_order` constants doesn't mean they don't do anything. Even on x86 (which has strongly ordered memory semantics), the choice of `memory_order` changes compiler optimization/reordering restrictions; two `memory_order_relaxed` operations in a row can be swapped by the compiler, so the second operation appears to occur first. Similarly, `relaxed` or `release` `store`s are generally zero overhead, but with `memory_order_seq_cst`, the compiler adds explicit, expensive (~100 cycle delay) `mfence` instructions.

Comment: on x86 at least specifying memory order can get rid of the `lock` prefix in some cases (assuming the operation can be completed in one cycle) whereas most compilers will issue the `lock` prefix without it, it's not a huge delay [~100-500 cycles](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35470628/332733) depending on chip, but still... that's a LOT more expensive than an ordinary increment.

Comment: @Mgetz In which case can you avoid the `lock` prefix on an operation?

Comment: @ShadowRanger "_the choice of memory_order changes compiler optimization/reordering restrictions_" In theory: yes it does. In practice: which compiler optimizes based on memory orders?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Which ordering is esoteric?

Comment: @curious I do not understand the question.  If you want to know what memory model features of C++ are irrelivant on what platforms in practice, you can use the [ask question] button.  Note that hardware limits and optimizer assumptions may differ.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont You seemed to suggest that some values of memory order were rarely if even practically useful, on normal hardware.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Since you say you're targeting x86 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153905/least-restrictive-memory-ordering-for-spin-lock-with-two-atomics#comment58637089_35470628), you're [guaranteed strongly-ordered memory anyway](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release-Acquire_ordering); avoiding `memory_order_seq_cst` is useful (it can trigger expensive and unnecessary memory fences), but beyond that, most other operations won't impose any special overhead, so you won't gain anything from additional relaxation aside from allowing possibly incorrect compiler instruction reordering. This should be safe, and no slower than any other solution using C++11 atomics:

```
void Foo::Modify()
{
    while( locked.test_and_set( std::memory_order_acquire ) ) ;
    while( workers_busy.load( std::memory_order_acquire ) != 0 ) ; // acq to see decrements
    // ....
    locked.clear( std::memory_order_release );
}

void Foo::DoWork( SomeContext& )
{
    while(locked.test_and_set(std::memory_order_acquire)) ;
    workers_busy.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed); // Lock provides acq and rel free
    locked.clear(std::memory_order_release);
    // ....
    workers_busy.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel); // No lock wrapping; acq_rel
}
```

At worst, on x86, this imposes some compiler ordering constraints; it shouldn't introduce additional fences or lock instructions that don't need to be locked.

Answer (score -6):

You should avoid using the c++ version of the test and set lock. Instead you should use the atomic instructions provided by the compiler. This actually makes a big difference. This will work with gcc and is a test and test and set lock which is a bit more efficient that the standard test and set lock.

```
unsigned int volatile lock_var = 0;
#define ACQUIRE_LOCK()   {                                                                           
                    do {                                                                    
                        while(lock_var == 1) {                                              
                            _mm_pause;                                                    
                        }                                                                   
                    } while(__sync_val_compare_and_swap(&lock_var, 0, 1) == 1);              
                }
#define RELEASE_LOCK()   lock_var = 0
//
```

The _mm_pause is recommended by Intel for there processors so there is time for the lock to update.

Your thread will only exit the do while loop when it obtains the lock and then enter the critical section.

If you look at the documentation for the __sync_val_compare_and_swap you will notice this is based of the xchgcmp instruction and will have the word lock above it in the generated assembly to lock the bus while this instruction is taking place. This guarentees an atomic read modify write.

Comment: Do you have numbers behind "makes a big difference"? The design you specify might be somewhat faster than correct use of atomics with acquire/release semantics, but it's also not imposing any ordering constraints on the compiler; the action of `RELEASE_LOCK` at the very least could be reordered (by the compiler, though on x86, not the CPU thanks to strong ordering guarantees) to occur before mutations that should be protected by the lock, so you'd wouldn't avoid the race conditions you're trying to prevent. It's also non-portable to non-Intel (possible non-x86) architectures.

Comment: Yeah I know about `_mm_pause`, and am already using it.  I left it out of my question because it didn't seem relevant.  To my knowledge, `std::atomic_flag` will translate to exactly the same `xchgcmp` instruction.  However, I am not convinced that simply setting the value to zero instead of doing an atomic clear will end up being atomic, nor will it have predictable memory ordering.

Comment: Yeah this is a part of my masters thesis subject and it makes about 10% difference to performance. If you want ordering you need to look at something like the Bakery lock which will order based on when a thread tries to acquire the lock. The Black and White Bakery or MCS locks would provide ordering as well but are not as simple

Comment: While your thread has the lock what you do doesn't need to be atomic so it doesn't matter simply setting it to 0 work.

Comment: Something I left out is the lock must be volatile. If the lock is not volatile then it won't force a read from memory when the variable is checked which would mean the lock won't work

Comment: @DanielDowd: What prevents code is `ACQUIRE_LOCK(); ++x; RELEASE_LOCK();` from being reordered by the compiler to `ACQUIRE_LOCK(); RELEASE_LOCK(); ++x;`? Without compiler supported ordering constraints, the latter is perfectly reasonable; two threads could each acquire and release the lock (only one at a time, but with race conditions, both can be assumed to begin executing code after exiting the lock simultaneously), and now you've got a classic race condition on the increment.

Comment: @DanielDowd: Ah, yeah, that makes a huge difference. That said, officially, `volatile` doesn't impose memory ordering either; it requires that the read and write occur, but doesn't require it to occur in a specific order relative to accesses to other variables, so I doubt `volatile` would fix this even by the standard. On the compilers that do implement `volatile` in a way that makes it useful for threading, they're often imposing behavior equivalent to `memory_order_seq_cst`, with a full memory fence; not likely to yield a big savings.

Comment: If it makes a difference, I'm targeting x86 architectures for Mac OS X and Windows (compiling with Clang and MSVC++, respectively).

Comment: You put the ACQUIRE_LOCK(); before the critical section and RELEASE_LOCK() after the critical section. That stops compiler reordering.   This works with clang also since clang support gcc's naming convention for the atomic calls they have defined with the horrible __sync in front of them.

Comment: @DanielDowd: [`RELEASE_LOCK` imposes no such constraints even if `lock_var` is `volatile`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Relationship_with_volatile): "...volatile accesses ... do not order memory (non-volatile memory accesses may be freely reordered around the volatile access)", so nothing prevents the reordering I described. It does note "One notable exception is Visual Studio, where, with default settings, every volatile write has release semantics and every volatile read has acquire semantics", but that's Visual Studio specific, not a language guarantee.

Comment: In order to use volatile for a flag, you often need to make all your shared objects also volatile. It's very rarely what you want or even can do.